# DllExport in a broker dll from VBA with reference to other .NET projects

Tags: c#, vba, unmanaged, dllexport

I want to use [DllExport](https://github.com/3F/DllExport), in a dll which has a broker-function: routing some calls from external code (VBA) to other .NET dll's behind.

I got the DllExport working on a single dll: the dll is generated, and I can use it. But... only with code from that single dll.
When I call code from another (in .NET referenced) dll, the solution still builds, I still can use the code from the dll with dllexport, but when calling a method that routes to the referenced dll, VBA gives me a 'Could not load file or assembly 'myseconddllname, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of iets dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I also tried to add DllExport to the second dll (which shouldn't be necessary, no objects/info from the second dll should be exposed to Unmanaged code). This didn't help.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Edit: registered an issue on github: [Calling referenced .NET assembly](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/86)

Comment: It is a very brittle way to implement interop.  Remarkable that you got a good exception, that doesn't happen all that often.  The CLR uses normal lookup rules for dependent assemblies, it first looks in the GAC and next in the same directory as the EXE.  if you made it hard to find in an arbitrary other directory then it is sayonara.  If you have a good "always call this first" kind of method then you could make AppDomain.AssemblyResolve work.  But the GAC is certainly a good idea, this has lots of DLL Hell attached.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look into the AssemblyResolve.
GAC isn't the way to go for me. I just try to prevent admin-rights for distribution of this software. When admin-rights are needed, I can simply register the dll with ComVisible, without using DllExport.

Comment: by the way: my dll is in the same folder, I'm familiar with the both levels of looking up assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant I've a single entrypoint, where I added:
            string assemblyFile = $@"{new FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).DirectoryName}\mysecondlibrary.dll";
            Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);

this gives a full crash of my Access-application when executing from VBA, without any exception/message.

Comment: Hmm, it would be wise the honor the user's IT staff intentions.  They do this to prevent them from installing anything that is likely to make their everyday software malfunction in a hard-to-diagnose way without them knowing about it.  You are going to need their assistance, don't piss them off.

Comment: And yes, not getting a decent diagnostic is DllExport's achilles heel.  Create an Office add-in instead.

Comment: I'm working together with IT staff, no problems with pissing them off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others reference: with help from here and github-issue found the solution:

Having two projects:

1. ClassLibrary1 to call from VBA
2. ClassLibrary2 to be used from within ClassLibrary1 (without exposing something to VBA)

In ClassLibrary1 we've a static class UnmanagedExport:

```
static class UnmanagedExport
{
    static UnmanagedExport()
        => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        => Assembly.LoadFrom($@"{new FileInfo(args.RequestingAssembly.Location).DirectoryName}\{args.Name.Split(',')[0]}.dll");

    [DllExport]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
    static object CreateBroker()
        => new Class1();
}
```

CreateBroker() creates an instance of Class1 (which is supposed to be the broker between VBA and ClassLibrary2).
ClassLibrary1.Class1:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Class1
{
    public void DoNothingOnClass2Typed()
        => new Class2().DoNothing();

    public void CreateClass2aFromClass2Typed()
        => new Class2().CreateClass2a();
}
```

Class2 (and Class2a) are both in ClassLibrary2 (which is referenced by ClassLibrary1):

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public void DoNothing()
        {
            return;
        }

        public void CreateClass2a()
        {
            var class2a = new Class2a();
        }
    }
}
```

From VBA this is called as:

```
Declare Function CreateBroker Lib "C:\source\repos\DllExportTest\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" () As Object


Public Sub RunTest()
  Dim class1 As Object

  Set class1 = CreateBroker()

  class1.DoNothingOnClass2Typed

  class1.CreateClass2aFromClass2Typed

  Set class1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Works like a charm!

**Note:** ClassLibrary2 can also be a .NET Standard dll, so the solution is compatible with .NET Core also.